# How can I communicate over USB in ROS 2?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to convert a ROS 1-package into a ROS 2-package. The purpose of the package is to communicate with a robot over USB. Therefore for ROS 1 I used the file serial.h to connect to USB and to write to USB. Is there a similar way in ROS 2 to communicate over USB?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401201/how-can-i-communicate-over-usb-in-ros-2?/) by [hondaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/105847/hondaser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-05-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can make your own node in ROS 2 either in python or CPP,

I have worked with Python, below is the code for that, you can use library serial in python, and you need to convert it to ros2 code based on your requirements.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate=9600, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                            stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, timeout=10000)
if ser.is_open == True:
            return True
        else:
            return False

while (ser.is_open == True):
            line = ser.read_until(b'#')
```

In case of any ques, feel free to drop commet.

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2022-05-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your robot is running off a small microcontroller and you want to communicate over ROS2 via serial you can utilize micro-ROS as found here: https://micro.ros.org/

In ROS1 there is also the rosserial package, which encompasses the popular rosserial_arduino package that can also do the same. They have a tutorials page on the ROS1 wiki [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials)

Again this would mainly apply if your robot is running off a microcontroller, which is the most common use case as to why you would run serial operations. If you are instead using a small computer (not q microcontroller) outfitted with Ethernet or Wi-Fi, this would be a more preferred way to communicate over ROS.

---

Originally posted by [808brick](https://answers.ros.org/users/51297/808brick/) with karma: 153 on 2022-05-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-05-30**:
Keep in mind that micro-ROS does not support 8bit microcontrollers, where ROS1 serial did.